# PHP Square Root Calculator (w/ HTML)

Tags: php, html

I've attempted to make a square root calculator with PHP and HTML using form. but it won't seem to get the output statement. Here it is:

```
    <?php
$num = $_POST['getroot'];
$pull_sqrt = print(sqrt($num));
print("The Square root of "$num"is "$pull_sqrt);
?>

<form action="root.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="getroot" value="Number"/>
<input type="submit" id="submitroot" value="Calculate"/>
</form>
```

for root.php:

```
<?php
$num = $_POST['getroot'];
$pull_sqrt = print(sqrt($num));
print("The Square root of "$num"is "$pull_sqrt);
?>
```

Please help me out on explaining this, I still don't know if PHP allowed sqrt(); as a function anymore. Any way of re-editing is fine, I would like an explained way of fixing this. Thanks!

Comment: What does the php error log say?

Comment: @Quirliom, "Undefined post set from '$pull_sqrt' expected '{'"

Comment: @user3648388 You're missing some concatenation operators `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a form element named `getroot`

You want to do `<input type="text" id="getroot" name="getroot" value="Number"/>`

You cannot rely on just an `id`. POST requires a "named" element.

You're also missing concatenates for `print("The Square root of "$num"is "$pull_sqrt);`

***Sidenote:*** Remove `print` from `$pull_sqrt = print(sqrt($num));` otherwise it will echo as `1`.

do

```
print("The Square root of " . $num . "is " .$pull_sqrt);
```

---

Since you're using this in one page, you need to use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and using `action=""`.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$num = $_POST['getroot'];
$pull_sqrt = sqrt($num);
print("The Square root of " . $num  . " is " . $pull_sqrt);

}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="getroot" name="getroot"  placeholder="Enter a number"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitroot" value="Calculate"/>
</form>
```

---

You can also check if it is in fact a number that has been entered, using [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(is_numeric($_POST['getroot'])){
      $num = (int)$_POST['getroot'];
      $pull_sqrt = sqrt($num);
      print("The Square root of " . $num  . " is " . $pull_sqrt);

// Yes, you can do the following:
$pull_sqrt = print($num * $num); // added as per a comment you left, but deleted.
}

else{
echo "You did not enter a number.";
}

}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="getroot" name="getroot"  placeholder="Enter a number"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitroot" value="Calculate"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Possibly may you set it in a php form?

Comment: You're also missing concatenates as stated in comments. @user3648388

Comment: @user3648388 Yes it is possible to do `$pull_sqrt = print($num * $num);`